# Question closed for duplicating off-topic question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54110/after-finishing-job-how-to-phrase-request-that-any-further-volunteer-work-mus?noredirect=1&lq=1) was closed as a duplicate of [This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52829/on-last-day-manager-made-changes-to-the-program-that-broke-it-and-wants-me-to-co), but the latter question was closed as being "off topic".

This seems strange to me. If the first question is on-topic, it shouldn't be the duplicate of an off-topic question. Contrarily, if the first question is off-topic, that should be the close reason, not the duplication.

Or am I misunderstanding how duplicates and off-topic determinations are intended to work?

Comment: Close reasons are not rigorous. When several are considered correct, as in this case, any if those may be chosen.

Comment: If the result is that both questions are closed, I don't see how it matters if the reason was "because they are duplicates and the original was off-topic" or "because they are both off-topic". What's the practical difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One effect of a duplicate is that it channels people who come across the question to one that (probably) already has answers.  Even if both questions should be closed for other reasons, linking them together seems friendlier to me than closing them independently.  When a duplicate target is available (and is really a duplicate), some people will therefore prefer that close reason over others.

Further, as noted in a comment, sometimes multiple close reasons apply.  I've seen questions that managed to get votes for off-topic *and* primarily opinion-based *and* too broad, for instance.  In the end there can be only one (in the banner).

Answer (score -1):

my understanding is there are certain question criteria that have to be met to be considered off topic. that could be the reason it was tagged off topic. but when the question was asked again (maybe while the first was still not closed), it was tagged as duplicate.